# Многопоточность в Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Допустим есть 1000 урл. Хочу каждый урл загрузить в браузер, получить данные. Какой оптимальный метод организации `многопоточного` пула для `Selenium`?

Answer (score 1):

селениум для такого не предназначен. Он предназначен для тестирования, а не граббинга/кравлинга.

> Какой оптимальный метод организации многопоточного пула для Selenium?

но если хочется все сделать именно на селениуме, то ничто тебе не мешает создавать в отдельных потоках/тасках создание инстанса WebDriver и делать что тебе заблагоразсудится с ним в этом отдельном потоке.

Все будет работать в паралели, как ты и хочешь. Только жрать оперативку будет сильно.

Comment: А как узнать свободен ли таск или нет?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=netframework-4.7.2